# Multiple projects: symbols seem to be unloaded

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, breakpoints

I have a WebApi project, and an MVC project that consumes the WebApi project through RESTful calls.

I set my VS 2013 Professional system to start both projects at the same time.

If I run either project alone, I can set and capture breakpoints.  If I run both projects, only breakpoints in the WebApi project are available.  How do I fix this?  As far as I can tell, there are no version issues with any common assemblies, and the multitude of answers on SO do not seem to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the answer is shouting curse words at your monitor.  After restarting IIS Express, Visual Studio, and my machine multiple times, Cleaning the solution multiple times, changing the build config back and forth multiple times, it just started working all of a sudden.  No code or configuration changes. Whoever said insanity is doing the same thing repeatedly and expecting a different result was clearly not a developer.  Either that or I'm insane.  (could be both)